# Determining how long a trip takes in minutes

Tags: c#

Have the user enter an arrival time such in the format 3:30 PM
Then ask the user how long it takes to get to their destination.
I then need to display the time they need to leave in order to arrive to their destination on time.

I have this so far

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the arrival time <e.g. 3:30 PM>:");
DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("How long is the trip time in minutes:");
string date = Console.ReadLine();
DateTime durationOfTrip = DateTime.Parse(date);

TimeSpan diff = time.Subtract(durationOfTrip);
Console.WriteLine(diff);
Console.ReadLine();
```

I get this error 
An unhandled exception of type `System.FormatException` occurred in `mscorlib.dll`

```
Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please add the `homework` tag.

Comment: What is your interpretation of the error message?

Comment: Check out the AddMinutes method on the [DateTime structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx)

Comment: @Dennis There is no `homework` tag on Stack Overflow. It was [officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) long ago, and has now been removed completely. The same standards apply for homework questions as for *all* questions.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you're trying to parse the string "3:30 PM" into an instance of DateTime. You'll need to use a custom parse string:

```
string arrivalInput = Console.ReadLine();
var arrival =
    DateTime.ParseExact(
        arrivalTimeInput,
        "hh:mm tt",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    );
```

This *will* parse the time, but it will set the date component to today.

Unfortunately, there is just no clean encapsulation of *time* only in the framework.

Then your next problem is

```
string date = Console.ReadLine();
DateTime durationOfTrip = DateTime.Parse(date);
```

where you're trying to parse something like "30" into a `DateTime`. That's clearly not going to fly. You told the user to enter the input in minutes, so convert the input to an instance of `TimeSpan`:

```
string durationInput = Console.ReadLine();
var duration = new TimeSpan(0, Int32.Parse(durationInput), 0);
```

or

```
var duration = TimeSpan.ParseExact(s, "mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then, what you need to do is [subtract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae6246z1.aspx) `duration` from `arrival`, this will give you a new instance of `DateTime`, and then you need to use an appropriate format string to only output the time.

Note that I've given your variable names slightly more meaningful names. The name `date` for the user input trip duration was particularly unclear.

Comment: I still get the same error using 
string durationInput = Console.ReadLine();
var duration = new TimeSpan(0, Int32.Parse(durationInput), 0);

I managed to get a little further, however now the answer comes out in the wrong format.

Comment: It's impossible for you to get the same error on those two lines. Your error is about parsing a `DateTime`: "*String was not recognized as a valid `DateTime`*." Since the lines that you are claiming the same error occurs on are not about parsing a `DateTime`, it's impossible.

Comment: @Jason your `ParseExact` code doesn't set the date portion to 1/1/0001, it sets it to today. E.g. right now parsing `01:00 pm` with your code produces `8/4/2013 1:00:00 PM`. This means that subtracting 120 minutes will usually produce a sensible time, not crash.

Comment: I have this
onsole.WriteLine("Enter the arrival time <e.g. 3:30 PM>:");
            string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
          //  var duration = new TimeSpan(0, Int32.Parse(userInput), 0);
            DateTime arrTime = Convert.ToDateTime(userInput);
            Console.WriteLine("How long is the trip time in minutes:");
            int userInput2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            var result = arrTime.AddMinutes(-userInput2);
var wholeDate = result;
            var time = wholeDate - wholeDate.Date;

 Console.WriteLine("You must leave at  " + time);

Comment: @Tim S.: Oh, thanks Tim S. You're right, I just checked the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h3syy57.aspx): "*If the string representation specifies only a time, parsing returns a `DateTime` object with its `Year`, `Month`, and `Day` properties set to the corresponding values of the `Today` property*."

Comment: You wrote: "*`Console.WriteLine("Enter the arrival time <e.g. 3:30 PM>:"); string userInput = Console.ReadLine(); // var duration = new TimeSpan(0, Int32.Parse(userInput), 0);`*" No, that won't work. You need to parse *that* input as an instance of `DateTime` as I outlined at the top of my post, not as a `TimeSpan`. The `Int32.Parse` will **bomb** if you try to pass it `userInput = "3:30 PM"`. It's the duration that you need to parse as a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: Alright i started fresh only using your code. It doesnt like "CultureInfo" What exactly does it do? It says it does not exist.

Comment: It's `CultureInfo`, not `CultureInfor`. You *could* [Google](https://www.google.com/#gs_rn=23&q=CultureInfo) it and it will tell you that it's in the `System.Globalization` namespace. It's used to tell, among other things, parsing routines how to interpret strings that can vary from culture to culture. It's relevant to dates because people all over the world have an insane variety of ways to write dates.

Comment: I must still be doing so,something wrong, because i still get the same error. 
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter the arrival time <e.g. 3:30 PM):");
            string arrivalInput = Console.ReadLine();
            var arrival =
                DateTime.ParseExact(
                    arrivalInput,
                    "hh:mm tt",
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
                );
            string durationInput = Console.ReadLine();
            var duration = new TimeSpan(0, Int32.Parse(durationInput), 0);

Comment: However this code works.
Console.WriteLine("Enter the arrival time <e.g. 3:30 PM>:");
            string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
          
            DateTime arrTime = Convert.ToDateTime(userInput);
            Console.WriteLine("How long is the trip time in minutes:");
            int userInput2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            var result = arrTime.AddMinutes(-userInput2);
            var wholeDate = result;
      var time = wholeDate - wholeDate.Date;
   Console.WriteLine("You must leave at  " + time); Console.ReadLine();
 But gives me the time in 24hour format.

Answer (score 0):

An average user would enter an integer number ("time in minutes"), and you're trying to parse this into a `DateTime` structure. How would .NET know what these numbers mean? They might as well be milliseconds.

The first step would probably be parsing the input to an `int`, and then using the `AddMinutes()` method JMK mentioned to apply the minutes to the already created `DateTime time`.